# Recursive query to specific depth

Tags: recursion, graphql, relayjs

I have a tree structure which I'm trying to query to a specific depth.  I'm new to relay so not sure about if I'm going about this the right way or even if its possible.

My code is currently looking like this:

```
class TreeRoot extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var container = this.props.treeRoot;
    return (
      <div>
        <ViewNode viewNode={container.root} maxDepth={10} expand={true}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

class ViewNode extends React.Component {

   render() {
      var vn = this.props.viewNode;
      return (
       <div>
        <div>{vn.type} {vn.widget} {vn.mode}</div>
         <ViewNodeList viewNode={vn} maxDepth={this.props.maxDepth-1}/>
       </div>
      );
  }
}

ViewNode = Relay.createContainer(ViewNode, {
    initialVariables:{
        maxDepth:1,
        expand:false
    },
    fragments: {
      viewNode: (variables) => Relay.QL`
        fragment on ViewNode{
          id
          type
          widget
          mode
          viewNodes @include(if: $expand){
            ${ViewNode.getFragment("viewNode", {maxDepth:(variables.maxDepth -1),expand:(variables.maxDepth > 0)}).if(variables.expand)}
        }
    }`,
  }
});

class ViewNodeList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const vn = this.props.viewNode;
    if (!vn.viewNodes){
      return (<div></div>);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {vn.viewNodes.map((el, i)=> {
          return <ViewNode key={i} viewNode={el} maxDepth={this.props.maxDepth} expand={this.props.maxDepth > 0}></ViewNode>
        })
        }
      </div>
    );
  };
}

TreeRoot = Relay.createContainer(TreeRoot, {
    fragments: {
      root: () => Relay.QL`
          fragment on TreeRoot{
              id
              name
              root{
                  ${ViewNode.getFragment('viewNode',{maxDepth:10,expand:true})}
              }
           }
       `,
    }
  }
);
```

The significant bit being the way I'm trying to control the recursion in the ViewNode component's viewNode fragment.  It is attempting to recurse down while decrementing the 'maxDepth' variable and using the 'maxDepth' to calculate the value of the 'expand' variable.  Whether to continue recursing is based on the 'expand' var.

Currently this retrieves the root and the first level of children but doesn't recurse as desired.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?  If it is am I on the right track or going about this in completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern is to create a fragment for the content and then nest the elements in the query. E.g.

```
fragment ViewContent on ViewNode {
  name
}

query ViewQuery {
  root {
    viewNode {
      ...ViewContent
      viewNode {
        ...ViewContent
        viewNode {
           ...ViewContent
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```